# How to convert from Black body intensity to MJy/sr?

Tags: units, black-body

How does one convert from  ${\rm ergs\cdot cm^{-2}\cdot s^{-1} \cdot sr^{-1}\cdot Hz^{-1}}$ to ${\rm MJy \cdot sr^{-1}}$

and from ${\rm ergs\cdot cm^{-2}\cdot s^{-1} \cdot sr^{-1}\cdot cm^{-1}}$ to ${\rm MJy \cdot sr^{-1}}$

Comment: The first one is not difficult. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jansky) you would multiply by $10^{+23}$ if it were Jy/sr, but since it's MJy/sr you multiply by only $10^{+17}$.

Comment: The second one has likely been answered before in this site, have a look around. However if you'd like to try it yourself, start with $$f = \frac{c}{\lambda}$$ take the derivative to get $$\frac{df}{d \lambda} = -c\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$$ and rearrange to get  $$df = -c\frac{1}{\lambda^2} d \lambda$$ and use $c \approx 2.9979 \times 10^{10} \text{cm s}^{-1}$ Use that to convert your number in $\text{cm}^{-1}$ to $\text{Hz}^{-1}$ then use the info in the first comment to finish the conversion.

Comment: I can't guarantee these (haven't had my coffee yet), so posting as comments only, not as an answer.

Comment: @uhoh I compiled an answer, although you already answered it in principle in the comments (which I cite). The complication was actually the typesetting.

Comment: @B--rian you are brave!

Comment: @uhoh I do not quite understand, why brave? Because of citing you?

Comment: @B--rian no, it's a compliment! When I do these kinds of things I inevitably make little errors, and if I do the same thing five times I get three different answers. It's easy to write the equations, but to execute and get the correct result with certainty and then to post it as an answer is brave :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Part 1

On the one hand, ${\rm 1\, ergs\cdot cm^{-2}\cdot s^{-1} \cdot sr^{-1}\cdot Hz^{-1}} = 10^{-3} {\rm J}/({\rm m^2} \cdot {\rm sr})$ has basic dimensions ${\rm mass} \cdot {\rm time}^{-2} \cdot {\rm angle}^{-2}$ and is a **radio brightness**.

On the other hand, there is ${\rm 1 MJy}\cdot{\rm sr}^{-1} = 10^{-20} {\rm J}/({\rm m^2} \cdot {\rm sr})$ which has indeed the same basic units. A possible difficulties could be the conversion from [Jansky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jansky) to [SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units): $1\, {\rm Jy} = 10^{-26} {\rm W} \cdot {\rm m}^{-2} \cdot {\rm Hz}^{-1}$ and (less likely) the fact that ${\rm M}=10^6$. This said, there is a factor of $10^{-17}$ between the two values.

#### Part 2

We start with ${\rm 1\, ergs\cdot cm^{-2}\cdot s^{-1} \cdot sr^{-1}\cdot cm^{-1}} = 0.1 {\rm W}/({\rm sr \cdot m^2})/{\rm m} $ which is easily identified by [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+ergs+%2F+cm%5E3+%2F+s+%2F+sr) as unit for a **volume scattering emission coefficient**. This is not the same as the expression in part 1. However, since you state that it is about *Black body intensity*, you can follow the argumentation of [uhoh](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/7982/uhoh) in the comments to convert from a wavenumber (given in ${\rm cm}^{-1}$) to a frequency (in ${\rm Hz}$).

> However if you'd like to try it yourself, start with $f= c \lambda$, take the derivative to get
> $$\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}\lambda} = -c \frac{1}{\lambda^2} $$
> and rearrange to get
> $${{\rm d}\lambda} = -c \frac{1}{\lambda^2} {\rm d}\lambda$$
> derivative to get
> $${\rm d}f = -c \frac{1}{\lambda^2} {\rm d}\lambda$$
> and use $c \approx 2.9979\cdot10^{10} {\rm cm}\cdot{\rm s^{−1}}$. Use that to convert your number in ${\rm cm}^{−1}$ to ${\rm Hz}^{−1}$ [...]